# Why Test Match ends with draw instead of either win or loss?

Tags: cricket

If second batting of second innings didn't reach the target with still wickets in hand.

then it declare **draw** instead of giving win to first batting team of second innings, why so ?

But in ODI, second batting of first innings didn't reach the target with still wickets in hand then win will be given to first batting team.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because there's no restriction on how long the first team can bat. Imagine a ridiculously flat track where batting is very easy - the team winning the toss decides to bat, and bats for four days, scoring 1000 runs or so. The second team now begins their innings, and by the end of the fifth day has reached 300 without loss. Why should they be declared the loser?

Test Match cricket, or more generally timed cricket, involves a different set of skills from limited overs cricket - building pressure and taking wickets is paramount, run rate less so.

Comment: 1000 runs in 4 days on flat track seems very low :)